# Install JAX with CUDA via requirements.txt

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

I installed JAX[cuda] using the installation instructions from [official JAX Github](https://github.com/google/jax#installation): `pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html` which works nicely. Now I want to wrap this into a requirements.txt in order to save my environment.

I already tried `--pre --extra-index-url https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html "jax[cuda]"` within my requirements.txt but `pip install -r requirements.txt` always installs the CPU version, not the GPU version. Is there any trick to force the requirements-file to install the GPU / cuda release of JAX?

Comment: You used `-f`/`--find-links` in command line but `--extra-index-url` in `requirements.txt`

Comment: awesome, thank you! It works with --pre --find-links https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html "jax[cuda]" in the requirements file

Answer (score 1):

In a *pip* `requirements.txt` file, each global option should be written on its own individual line:

```
--pre

--find-links https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html

jax[cuda]
```

***References***

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#supported-options

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I wasn't aware that --pre is a global option. Anyway, is there a way to allow prereleases only for certain packages, i.e. a local prerelease option?